# what is MaxCapacityEX and MaxCapacity

Tags: windows, command-line

What is the difference between MaxCapacityEX and MaxCapacity
How do they use

https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemoryarray#examples

Answer (score 1):

According to the same page:

- `MaxCapacity` is an *uint32* value and can only describe at most 4 GiB (0xFFFFFFFF bytes) of physical memory.
- `MaxCapacityEx` is an *uint64* value and has no such limit.